# Why Query Output Different even if both the queries are same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL 2008 and running following Query.

```
Select ROUND(53.67*0.75,3)
```

Which gives me result = 40.2530

But same thing if i am checking with data stored in table it give me different output why?

```
Create table CalCheck
(GrossWeight float, Rate float) 
Go
Insert into CalCheck values (53.67,0.75)
GO
Select ROUND(GrossWeight*Rate,3) from CalCheck
```

Above query gives me result = 40.252

Why its showing 0.001 difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because SQL SERVER is interpreting the values as `DECIMALS` in the first example

```
Select ROUND(53.67*0.75,3)
```

Whereas the second example you are specifying `FLOATS`

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd8d7/3)

Further to that you could have a look at [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx)

> Returns the base data type and other information about a sql_variant
>   value.

```
Select  sql_variant_property(53.67*0.75,'BaseType') BaseType, 
        sql_variant_property(53.67*0.75,'Precision') [Precision], 
        sql_variant_property(53.67*0.75,'scale') [Scale]
```

From [Using decimal, float, and real Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> **The float and real data types are known as approximate data types. The behavior of float and real follows the IEEE 754 specification on
>   approximate numeric data types.**
>
> Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified
>   for many numbers; they store an extremely close approximation of the
>   value. For many applications, the tiny difference between the
>   specified value and the stored approximation is not noticeable. At
>   times, though, the difference becomes noticeable. Because of the
>   approximate nature of the float and real data types, do not use these
>   data types when exact numeric behavior is required, such as in
>   financial applications, in operations involving rounding, or in
>   equality checks. Instead, use the integer, decimal, money, or
>   smallmoney data types.
>
> The IEEE 754 specification provides four rounding modes: round to
>   nearest, round up, round down, and round to zero. Microsoft SQL Server
>   uses round up. **All are accurate to the guaranteed precision but can
>   result in slightly different floating-point values. Because the binary
>   representation of a floating-point number may use one of many legal
>   rounding schemes, it is impossible to reliably quantify a
>   floating-point value.**

Comment: float datatypes converts preceding number + 1 if its having more then 5? and decimal converts preceding number + 1 if having 5 digit like that?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that SQL Server can probably not represent the number exactly, so it might be slightly less than 40.2525, something like 40.252499999 which then rounds down. 40.2545 rounds up to 40.255 as expected originaly.